# list of textareas in django forms

Tags: django

I have a cms-like page where users can create their own simple pages, with a title, image and some content. The form I'm using for it is the following:

```
class PageForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Helper form for the cms backoffice page.
    """
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    preview_image  = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 20, 'rows': 10}))
```

But now I want to enhance this by adding multiple sections to a page. The thing is these are optional, so user can choose to only leave one section, in which case this form should do it, but then have a button 'add section' or something which can will add an extra TinyMCE and ImageField to the UI, also Delete section will delete one.

Now the way I see it this is a long shot, but is there any way I could model this using django forms? The way I'm thinking now if I limit the number of forms to a given number, I could add content_i and preview_image_i to the form and then check which one were submitted. That should work right? Is there any way to do it without a maximum number of sections? Otherwise how much of an overhead would I be adding if I add 100 CharFields / ImageFields which would be used rarely to a full extent (if at all).

Or should I just abandon django forms for this and do some custom handling?

Thanks